# How do i get this fancy "path bar with git icons" as shown in this picture of zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

How do i get this fancy "path bar with git icons" as shown in this picture of zsh?

What is it called?

[image: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-523652?sign=MTYyMTU5NDgwMDAwMHwxMS0zNTI5ODZ8NzQtNTIzNjUyfEhoT3FUZjNrdm5yS1RIZFJoRkNNWEM0%0D%0ARzBmQVVGSnJmVUZnYzdOdFpmUncNCg%0D%0A&updated=0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Zsh theme called [agnoster](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme), which works in conjunction with [Powerline-patched fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) to display those symbols.

It’s available in [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#agnoster).